# Missing or insufficient permissions, al agregar un string a firebase con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firestore

estoy trabajando con React.js y quiero agregar un string a la collection "stories" en firebase, pero me sale el error y no se me ocurre que puede ser, ayuda por favor.

```
async createNewStory(story) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.db
        .collection("stories")
        .add({
          avatar: story,
          label: "Prueba",
          items: [],
        })
        .then(() => resolve(story))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Revisa el apartado sobre la seguridad](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics). Es probable que hayas restringido el acceso a ese documento y por tanto no puedas escribir en él.

Comment: Excelente, tenia un error de permisos, muchas gracias!